# Opposite of friend declaration

Tags: c++, c++17, friend

Say we have a class that has a private constructor, through `friend` we can allow some specific class(es) to still create objects of this class:

```
class Foo
{
 friend class Bar;
private:
  Foo();
};

class Bar
{
  Bar()
  {
    //create a Foo object
  }
};
```

---

Now what if I want the opposite of `friend`, where `Foo` looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
 //enemy/foe??? class Bar; (if only)
public:
  Foo();
};
```

And then no method of `Bar` can access the `Foo` constructor/ make an object of `Foo` but other classes can (because it's `public`).

```
class Bar
{
  Bar()
  {
    Foo foo; //compiler error
  }
};
```

Is such a construct possible or am I stuck with keeping `Foo` private and adding friends for all the classes?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The reason is one must keep their friends close, but their enemies even closer. ;)

Comment: Why would you even want that? Sounds like your design has issues. `friend` should be used sparingly; if you have to use it for "all the classes", you did something wrong.

Comment: @SebastianRedl That's why I dont want to take the `friend` everything but `Bar` approach, re-read the question. `Bar` shouldn't be able to access `Foo`, it's way more complicated in the real world example but I have a good reason for it. Right now, `Foo`'s constructor is public and no `friend` is used.

Comment: "I have a good reason for it." - I'm extremely curious.

Comment: @SebastianRedl `Bar` contains transactional logic for a microcontroller and `Foo` allows access through a legacy API to some parts of that controller. Used interchangeably can cause issues. Runtime checks are already in-place so even if it happens accidentally it won't cause a problem per se but I'd rather have a compile time error added to explain why it's not allowed.

Comment: That sounds like you more generically want to prohibit `Foo` and `BetterFoo` from being used in parallel, not specifically disallow `Bar` from using `Foo`. (You can't do that either, but ...)

Comment: @SebastianRedl Fair enough ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done really, but maybe following is enough for you:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag {};

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Foo(Tag<T>) {}

    Foo(Tag<Bar>) = delete;

    // ...
};
```

And so asking "creator" to "identify" itself.

```
class Bar
{
    Bar()
    {
        Foo foo{Tag<Bar>{}}; //compiler error

        // Foo foo{Tag<void>{}}; // valid as we can cheat about identity.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Such a thing does not exist, and it would be extremely pointless. Imagine you have a situation like this:

```
class Foo
{
  enemy class Bar;

public:
  Foo() {}
};

class Bar
{
  void evil() { Foo{}; }
};
```

Nothing prevents the implementor of `Bar` from doing this:

```
class Bar
{
  void evil() { do_evil(*this); }
};

void do_evil(Bar &self)
{
  Foo{};
}
```

`do_evil` is not a member of `Bar` (it's a global function), and so it's not an enemy. Such non-friendliness could therefore be trivially circumvented.

Comment: Fair enough, `#define private public` is one way too though :P. `const_cast` is also a dirty hack. For me it's not about making 100% sure that no matter how hard you try you can't make a `Foo` object, it's rather about emitting a compiler error inside the methods so the client knows they're probably doing something wrong messing with `Foo` inside `Bar` and thus shouldn't try to circumvent it.

Comment: @SombreroChicken The problem is that `#define provate public` leads to invalid code; this trivial workaround doesn't.

Comment: @SombreroChicken -  Redefining a language keyword using a macro gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SombreroChicken If you can modify `Bar`, you could declare a local `Foo` inside it to something nonsensical or something which will produce your desired error, so that using the name `Foo` will use the nested one and not the global one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept in C++.

Public attributes will always be public, but you can limit the exposure of `Foo` by making the constructor protected, for instance, and only visible for selected classes (although limiting `friend` is advised). Perhaps also make `Foo` as a protected class of `Bar2` because only `Bar2` or its children will actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been sayed by others, your desire breaks the idea of encapsulation because you cannot always know who your enemies are.

But, still, there is a possibility to get (almost) what you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct enemy;  // We need a forward declaration of your enemy

struct my_class {

    // The access is done using a factory, where the caller has to tell
    // us his own name
    template <class T>
    struct make{
        static_assert(!std::is_same<T,enemy>::value,"you are my enemy.");
        friend T;
    private:
        my_class operator() () { return my_class{}; }
    };


private:
    my_class(); // This is the constructor we care about

};

struct no_enemy {
    void bar() {
        my_class a = my_class::make<no_enemy>{}();  // works
    }
};


struct enemy {
    void bar() {
        my_class b = my_class::make<enemy>{}();     // error: static_assert failed
        my_class c = my_class::make<no_enemy>{}();  // error: foo is "private"
    }
};
```